# How do "traditional" and Nagaoka magnetism differ in their mechanism

Tags: magnetic-fields, low-temperature-physics

I see that Nagaoka magnetism is a low-temperature quantum effect from "minimizing" the energy of the system, but that explanation, while erudite, doesn't really explore any specifics - nearly all low temperature quantum effects happen as the system finds a lower energy state and lots of those have nothing to do with magnetism. From what I've read, it was first theorized with a square geometry and electron holes, and that it has now been successfully found and measured with "doublons" on a triangular geometry. I can't really understand why magnetism would happen here.

Meanwhile, I understand regular old ferromagnetism to be a condition where the spins of "the electrons" (guessing one or two per atom) distribute themselves such that their magnetic moments point in the same direction and this alignment has varying levels of stability depending on the temperature, material and an applied magnetic field. Because the spins are aligned, there's a net "permanent" magnetism to the material.

So, a) how wrong about either am I, and b) what's a more detailed explanation of Nagaoka magnetism?

Comment: in mainstream physics, it is a basic tenet that all classical theories emerge from the underlying quantum mechanical states of the system described. so " I can't really understand why magnetism would happen here" you should study the mathematics of the underlying quantum theory to be able to undestand.